# MobaXterm: edit pasted command before execution

Tags: linux, shell, copy-paste, mobaxterm

Hi everyone in this great community!
I am using MobaXterm - in my opinion it's a great tool for everyday routine with Win\Linux servers.

My question is about copy-paste procedure and Linux command execution. When I copy some command from some site, sometimes it executes immediately after pasting this command to some terminal via MobaXterm. I've found that reason is break in code: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377259/stop-terminal-auto-executing-when-pasting-a-command)

For example I see break in code after pasting command via MovaXterm. How can I edit it just before I hit OK? [Field with "mc" and break symbol is grey and I cannot change anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th8d9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can only do two things:

a) Copy the command to text editor and remove line breaks

b) Disable the warning and paste the command with line break.

1. Settings
2. Configuration
3. Terminal
4. Untick [Warn before pasting multiple lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDJl2.png)

I strongly advise to go with option A.

Comment: This was tweaked in Version 12.0 (2019-07-28)
Improvement: when pasting multiple lines, a popup window allows you to edit the clipboard content

Answer (score 0):

The copy paste buffer window is editable.
Notice the cursor circled in red, visible in the image snippet below
Simply click on the snippet in the text window, edit and then click 'Ok'
[image]